# AOT error : ng build --prod giving error in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, angular2-aot

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Lambda not supported.
 {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Lambda not supported","line":45,"character":23}
```

I have upgraded my `Angular 6` app to `Angular 7`. I am running `ng build --prod` with `aot: true` and getting above error. It was working fine before upgrading to `Angular 7`

**CODE: This is where it's getting error**

```js
public static request(requestUrl: string, options?: RequestInit): Promise<FetchResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(requestUrl, options)
        // .then(HelperFetch.parseJSON)
        .then((response: any) => {
          const resolver = new Resolver();
          // other code
          return <any> resolver.promise;
        })        
        .catch((error) => reject(new FetchResponse({

        })));
    });
  }
```

Anybody know what can be the problem? and How to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/696 may help

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have applied some solutions which i found online but none of them worked for me. I don't know why it was not giving any error before and now it's giving this error. That doesn't make any sense to me.